# how to get value from several input and make it become one input?

Tags: javascript

I have input that generate from database, if database have 3 input variables than PHP will loop 3x each input variables. Now I want to make input text (let's call it `new input box`) that get value when user type value in each input variables. The format must be `value1,value2,value3` and so on depend on where user input value. If user not input value in input 2, than value in `new input box` will skipped value2 (as in the picture that I included). I want to make it all in Javascript. How can I do that? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this example will help you.
Input field and form already dynamic, but im using jQuery for more simple code.

Array form is temp when you call the input field using ajax from your database

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let form = Array('input_1', 'input_2', 'input_3', 'input_4');
  let html = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
    html += '<label>' + form[i] + '</label>';
    html += '<input type="text" class="input" id="' + form[i] + '"><br>';
  }

  $('#form').html(html);

  $('.input').on('keyup', function() {
    let temp = [];

    $(".input").each(function() {
      temp.push(this.value);
    });
   
    $('#new').val(temp.join(','));
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form"></div>
<br>
<label>New Input Box</label>
<input type="text" id="new">
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done a job like this recently. It might help you to get the idea.

```js
var full_name = document.getElementById("full_name");
function onChangeFname(x) {
    full_name.value = x + " ";
}
function onChangeLname(x) {
    full_name.value = full_name.value + x + " ";
}
function onChangeLname(x) {
    full_name.value = full_name.value + x;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <label for="fname">First Name</label> <br />
    <input
        type="text"
        id="fname"
        name="fname"
        onChange="onChangeFname(this.value);"
    />
    <br />

    <label for="lname">Last Name</label> <br />
    <input
        type="text"
        id="lname"
        name="lname"
        onChange="onChangeLname(this.value);"
    />
    <br />

    <label for="full_name">Full Name</label> <br />
    <input type="text" id="full_name" name="full_name" /> <br />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is an example**

```js
// Get elements
const originalInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.original-val');
const newInput = document.querySelector('#new-val');

function displayNewVal() {
  // Put the 3 values into an array
  let arr = [];
  originalInputs.forEach(e => arr.push(e.value));

  // Combine them as a string
  let newVal = arr.join(',');
  
  // Set the string to the input value at the bottom
  newInput.value = newVal;
}

// When the page is loaded, execute the function
window.addEventListener('load', displayNewVal);

// When a value is changed, execute the function
originalInputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('change', displayNewVal));
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Aaaaa" class="original-val">
<br>
<input type="text" value="" class="original-val">
<br>
<input type="text" value="Ccccc" class="original-val">
<hr>
<input type="text" value="" id="new-val">
```

---

**Edit:**

Personally I don't recommend using Inline Event Handlers.

- ❌`<input onChange="myFunc()">`

For more information, see this:

- [Introduction to events - Learn web development | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these)

Comment: **Note:**
Next time, please post your code in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). StackOverflow is not a code writing service. You're expected to research and code by yourself first. It's okay if your code doesn't work well. We can help you fix bugs :)

Comment: I agree. Are you Chinese?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using jQuery for saving you from writing extra JS.

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  var arr = [];
  $( "input" ).each(function() {
    arr.push( $( this ).val());
  });
  
  console.log(arr.join(','));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="inpunt_1"> Input 1 </label>
<input name="input_1" value="value1" />
<br>
<label for="inpunt_2"> Input 2 </label>
<input name="input_2" value=" " />
<br>
<label for="inpunt_3"> Input 3 </label>
<input name="input_3" value="value3" />
<br>
<button>Save</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can achieve your functionality. Remember to pass index within each input element onChange function.

```js
const newValue = [];

    function inputFunc(value, index) {
        newValue.splice(index, 1, value)
        document.getElementById('newInput').value = newValue.join(',')
    }
```

```html
    <div>
        Inputs from database: 
        <input type="text" onchange="inputFunc(this.value, 0)" />
        <input type="text" onchange="inputFunc(this.value, 1)" />
        <input type="text" onchange="inputFunc(this.value, 2)" />
    </div>

    <div>
        New Input Value: 
        <input type="text" onchange="newInputFunc()" id="newInput" />
    </div>
```